# Parsing json output using jq -jr

Tags: json, jq

I am running a puppet bolt command query certain information from a set of servers in json format. I am piping it to jq.. Below is what I get

```
$ bolt command run "cat /blah/blah" -n @hname.txt -u uid --no-host-key-check --format json |jq -jr '.items[]|[.node],[.result.stdout]'

[
  "node-name"
][
  "stdout data\n"
]
```

What do I need to do to make it appear like below

```
["nodename":"stdout data"]
```

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid JSON value.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want output that is not valid JSON, you will have to construct the output string, which can easily be done using string interpolation, e.g.:

```
jq -r '.items[] | "[\"\(.node)\",\"\(.result.stdout)\"]"'
```

Comment: ["nodename","stdout data"]

Answer (score 0):

@peak thank you.. that helped. Below is how it looks like

```
$ bolt command run "cat /blah/blah" -n @hname.txt -u UID --no-host-key-check --format json |jq -r '.items[] | "[\"\(.node)\",\"\(.result.stdout)\"]"'
["node name","stdout data
"]
```

I used a work around to get the data I needed by using the @csv flag to the command itself. Sharing with you below what worked.

```
$ bolt command run "cat /blah/blah" -n @hname.txt -u uid --no-host-key-check --format json |jq -jr '.items[]|[.node],[.result.stdout]|@csv'
""node-name""stdout.data
"
```